# Chinese paintings

Tags: meaning

In our family a set of four Chinese paintings were called something that sounds like «daitse» or «die-tse» but we cannot find out the actual word and its meaning. Can anyone help? The theme of the set is four seasons and four classes.

Comment: What do you mean four classes? Are those school classes? Or four classes in society? like noble, merchants, warrior, worker?

Comment: would it be "題詩" /ti shī / (written poem)?

Answer (score 1):

Social classes, from left to right:
Winter, a man writing

Spring, a  man sitting on an ox

Summer, a couple making bundles of twigs

Autumn, a man fishing, a woman holding a basket

Answer (score -1):

i guess it's "代謝", when the theme is four seasons:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000042337

roughly means evolvement, replacement.

Comment: 代謝 bkrs dài xiè 交替 更替： **四时代谢**  |  **新陈代谢**  familiar to most users as **metabolism (biol.)**